# Dapper nested object with COUNT always returns 0

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper

I am trying to perform the following using Dapper and postgres.

I get all the images, with the comments for each model nested inside, but the vote total is always 0. I am thinking it's a mapping thing in Dapper as if I run the SQL manually in PGAdmin it returns correctly.

The model:

```cs
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public int VoteTotal { get; set; }
}
```

My repo code:

```cs
string sql = $"SELECT i.*, c.*, count(v.id) as votetotal " +
             $"FROM image i " +
             $"INNER JOIN comment c ON i.id = c.imageid " +
             $"INNER JOIN vote v ON i.id = v.imageid " +
             $"group by i.id, c.id;";

var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Image>();

connection.Query<Image, Comment, Image>(sql, (i, c) =>
{
    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(i.Id, out Image image))
    {
        lookup.Add(i.Id, image = i);
    }
    if (image.Comments == null) image.Comments = new List<Comment>();                                
    image.Comments.Add(c);                                
    return image;
}).AsQueryable();
```

The json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "google.com/animage",
    "dateTaken": "2000-01-01T00:00:00",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "imageId": 1,
            "commentText": "two comment",
            "createdBy": "Sam",
            "createdOn": "2021-03-05T13:39:21.065"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "imageId": 1,
            "commentText": "one comment",
            "createdBy": "Pam",
            "createdOn": "2021-03-05T13:39:21.065"
        }
    ],
    "voteTotal": 0
}
]
```

Comment: Isn't dapper mapping case sensitive?  You have `public int VoteTotal { get; set; }` versus `count(v.id) as votetotal`

Comment: I thought that but doesn't solve this issue unfortunately

Comment: Ended up going down the QueryMultiple route which works better.

Answer (score 0):

VoteTotal should go into the first mapping, because you have in the Image. It's last in the SQL when Comment already has been mapped, so it won't get mapped. You should change your SQL to:

```cs
string sql = @"SELECT count(v.id) as votetotal, i.*, c.*
               FROM image i INNER JOIN comment c ON i.id = c.imageid
               INNER JOIN vote v ON i.id = v.imageid
               GROUP BY i.id, c.id;";
```